# Error: Cannot read property "get" of undefined. How to use bot.channnels.get function?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.io

I'm unable to use the bot.channels.get function or whatever it is (apologies, i'm new to javascript and I don't know many of the terms). All I'm trying to do is send a test message using the bot. It tells me it's unable to read the property "get" of undefined.

Again, apologies. This is a mess of definitions that mostly don't get used anywhere else. I will clean it up afterwards.

```
const bot = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
const fs = require('fs');
var testfile = require('./testfile.txt')
//var bot = new Discord.Client();
var bots = new bot.Client({ token: "haha not for you", autorun: true });
const welcomeChannel = bot.channels.get('[channel id goes here]');
```

What I expect is to be able to assign welcomeChannel a channel id that can be used later to send messages:

```
welcomeChannel.send('message goes here');
```

Unfortunately the error mentioned earlier means that sending a message is impossible with the current code.

Comment: Did you mean `bots.channels.get`?

Comment: @melpomene same error now. That didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.channels.get('[channel id goes here]');
```

is `discord.js` Code

As you are using `discord.io` you have to do:

```
bots.sendMessage({
        to: channelID,
        message: "pong"
    });
```